# Read response body in Apache mod_lua

Tags: apache, lua, mod-lua

I'm prototyping a simple "output" filter with Apache + mod_lua. How can I read response body, at the end of other native output filters applied, via LUA? For example, can I get the actual response that  will be sent to the client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manual has some good guidance on this:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_lua.html#modifying_buckets

> Modifying contents with Lua filters Filter functions implemented via
>   LuaInputFilter or LuaOutputFilter are designed as three-stage
>   non-blocking functions using coroutines to suspend and resume a
>   function as buckets are sent down the filter chain. The core structure
>   of such a function is:

```
function filter(r)
    -- Our first yield is to signal that we are ready to receive buckets.
    -- Before this yield, we can set up our environment, check for conditions,
    -- and, if we deem it necessary, decline filtering a request alltogether:
    if something_bad then
        return -- This would skip this filter.
    end
    -- Regardless of whether we have data to prepend, a yield MUST be called here.
    -- Note that only output filters can prepend data. Input filters must use the 
    -- final stage to append data to the content.
    coroutine.yield([optional header to be prepended to the content])

    -- After we have yielded, buckets will be sent to us, one by one, and we can 
    -- do whatever we want with them and then pass on the result.
    -- Buckets are stored in the global variable 'bucket', so we create a loop
    -- that checks if 'bucket' is not nil:
    while bucket ~= nil do
        local output = mangle(bucket) -- Do some stuff to the content
        coroutine.yield(output) -- Return our new content to the filter chain
    end

    -- Once the buckets are gone, 'bucket' is set to nil, which will exit the 
    -- loop and land us here. Anything extra we want to append to the content
    -- can be done by doing a final yield here. Both input and output filters 
    -- can append data to the content in this phase.
    coroutine.yield([optional footer to be appended to the content])
end
```